# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/mightyanubhav/Desktop/reactportfolio/src/index.js' in '/Users/mightyanubhav/Desktop/reactportfolio'

Tags: reactjs, module, components

I'm trying to make a react webpage but getting below error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '/Users/mightyanubhav/Desktop/reactportfolio/src/index.js' in
> '/Users/mightyanubhav/Desktop/reactportfolio'

Please help me.

Comment: You can use the command "npx create-react-app my-app". For more information refer to: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/